# Disable phpmyadmin return headers

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find how to turn these off???  I simply want the query to display without them showing up every 100th row(user_id 500). I've looked thru a bunch of documentation but have had no luck.
Any suggestions to disable in the settings and/or query would be appreciated!!!

Return Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`$cfg['RepeatCells']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RepeatCells).

Simply add a line like `$cfg['RepeatCells'] = 0;` to your `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Setting the 'Headers every' option to 0 should do the trick.

Comment: Yea I actually tried that prior to posting, it seems to have no effect. I can put in 0, 100, 5000, etc but it always returns at every 100th line..??

Comment: Did u hit the 'Show' button after entering those numbers?

Comment: Yes It does seem to work with single table queries.  But if I do a join it seems to just always default to the every 100th row.